# how to map nested array in componentWillMount using react native

Tags: react-native

I am creating react-native app. I have an array and want to use value outside the looping. I have declared value in this.state={current_cat_id:'',} I have tried it in componentWillMount like:

```
componentWillMount() {
    var ids = [];
    this.props.data.map((dataImage,Index) => {
        dataImage['main-head'].map((subchild,Index2) => {
            ids.push(subchild['path'])  
            })

    })
    this.setState({current_cat_id: ids})
}
```

its returning blank page. is this right approch

Comment: check if "ids" is empty before setState. if not, paste the codes to show us how you use this.state.current_cat_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work for you. try this:-

```
componentWillMount() {
    var ids = [];
    this.props.data.map((dataImage) => {
        dataImage['main-head'] != undefined && dataImage['main-head'].map((subchild) => {
            ids.push(subchild['path'])  
            })        
    })
    this.setState({current_cat_id: ids})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

componentWillMount is called before the render method is executed. It is important to note that setting the state in this phase will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. Use componentDidMount() instead.